# Is secret needed in getToken method of NextAuth?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

In my API endpoint, it needed the user's session to verify if the user is authorized to make this request. In order to do so, I use

```
const session = await getToken({ req, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET })
```

This is the formal and correct way.
However, it also works perfectly fine if I do this without the secret:

```
const session = await getToken({ req })
```

If I don't explicitly pass the secret into the getToken method, does it automatically get it from the `NextAuth` object from `[...nextauth].js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only required to pass the secret to the `getToken` call if you have not set the `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` environment variable.

> The `getToken()` helper requires the following options:
>
> - `req` - (object) Request object
> - `secret` - (string) JWT Secret. Use `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` instead.
>
> — [NextAuth.js, Configuration Options, JWT Helper](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#jwt-helper)

In your case, since you have set `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` you do not need to pass `secret` to `getToken`.